# How to properly type a React ErrorBoundary class component in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-class-based-component, react-error-boundary

Here is my current attempt on how to properly type a React `ErrorBoundary` class component in Typescript:

```
import React from "react";
import ErrorPage from "./ErrorPage";
import type { Store } from "redux";   // I'M PASSING THE REDUX STORE AS A CUSTOM PROP

interface Props {
  store: Store         // THIS IS A CUSTOM PROP THAT I'M PASSING
}

interface State {      // IS THIS THE CORRECT TYPE FOR THE state ?
  hasError: boolean
}

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props,State> {
  
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error): State {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo): void {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    // logErrorToMyService(error, errorInfo);
    console.log("error: " + error);
    console.log("errorInfo: " + JSON.stringify(errorInfo));
    console.log("componentStack: " + errorInfo.componentStack);
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return(
        <ErrorPage
          message={"Something went wrong..."}
        />
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

This question is about the types for this `ErrorBoundary` class component. I'm breaking it into parts to make it easier.

---

**PART A: Types for props and state**

Is what I'm doing right?

```
interface Props {
  store: Store         // THIS IS A CUSTOM PROP THAT I'M PASSING
}

interface State {      // IS THIS THE CORRECT TYPE FOR THE state ?
  hasError: boolean
}

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props,State> {}
```

---

**PART B: getDerivedStateFromError(error)**

What type should I choose for the `error` parameter? The return type should be the `State` type, right?

```
static getDerivedStateFromError(error): State {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }
```

---

**PART C: componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo: React.React.ErrorInfo)**

What type should I choose for the `error` parameter? For the `errorInfo`, React does have a `ErrorInfo` type that seems to be correct. Is it? The return type should be `void`, correct?

```
componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo: React.ErrorInfo): void {
    console.log("error: " + error);
    console.log("errorInfo: " + JSON.stringify(errorInfo));
    console.log("componentStack: " + errorInfo.componentStack);
}
```

---

**PART D: the render() method**

Should the return type be `ReactNode` ?

```
render(): React.ReactNode {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return(
        <ErrorPage
          message={"Something went wrong..."}
        />
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
```

Comment: Is this syntax: import type { Store } from "redux"; allowed?

Comment: @captain-yossarian yes, it seems to be working just fine. But the `import type` syntax was release in a more recent version of Typescript, not sure which one, but it won't work in some older versions.

Comment: You should pass redux store to <Provider store={store}> and not directly to your Component

Comment: I'm doing that also. But not for the `ErrorBoundary`. But I guess I can access the store with `useStore()` from `react-redux` since the `ErrorBoundary` will be inside the `<Provider store={store}>`. Thanks. **EDIT:** actually I can't use `useStore` inside a class component. Just found that out. Got that error message: _React Hook "useStore" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function._

Comment: PART C:
This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Component<Record<string, never>, ErrorBoundaryState, any>'.ts(4114)
PART D:
This member must have an 'override' modifier because it overrides a member in the base class 'Component<Record<string, never>, ErrorBoundaryState, any>'.ts(4114)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will get all your answers in the file `index.d.ts` from `@types/react`. If you are using an IDE like VSCode, you can Ctrl+click on a type to directly go to its definition.

Here is the precise answers to your questions, but before, let me advise you to prefer using react `hooks` instead of classes.

---

**EDIT by OP:** I never use class components, always prefer function and hooks, but from React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) on Error Boundaries:

> *Error boundaries work like a JavaScript catch {} block, but for components. **Only class components can be error boundaries.***

---

The lines I give are the one from `index.d.ts` in version 16.9.49.

**Part A**: yes, that's the way to do.

**Part B**: as you can see at line 658, `error` is of type `any` and the return type is a partial of the `state` or `null`.

**Part C**: at line 641, you will see that error is of type `Error` and return type is `void`.

**Part D**: at line 494, you can see that render should return a `ReactNode`…

Comment: Thanks, man. I was just looking into the type definitions file right now. I forgot that those methods signatures would be inside the type definitions file. I decided to use `unknown` for the `error` parameter in `getDerivedStateFromError(error)`, instead of `any`.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the following code as an **Error Boundary**:

```
import React, { Component, ErrorInfo, ReactNode } from "react";

interface Props {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface State {
  hasError: boolean;
}

class ErrorBoundary extends Component<Props, State> {
  public state: State = {
    hasError: false
  };

  public static getDerivedStateFromError(_: Error): State {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  public componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
    console.error("Uncaught error:", error, errorInfo);
  }

  public render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Sorry.. there was an error</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exact following code and write ErrorBoundary.tsx file:

```
import { Component, ErrorInfo, ReactNode } from 'react';

import Spinner from './components/ui/Spinner.component';

interface ErrorBoundaryProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface ErrorBoundaryState {
  hasError: boolean;
}

class ErrorBoundary extends Component<ErrorBoundaryProps, ErrorBoundaryState> {
  constructor(props: ErrorBoundaryProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(_: Error): ErrorBoundaryState {
    // Update state to indicate an error has occurred
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, errorInfo: ErrorInfo): void {
    // You can log the error to an error reporting service
    console.error('Error caught by ErrorBoundary:', error, errorInfo);
  }

  render(): ReactNode {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return (
        <>
          <Spinner />
          <div>Something went wrong.</div>
        </>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

Then use it in index.tsx file:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary';
import { client } from './utils/graphql/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```